# how to Get an id of DOM elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm having some problems understanding the stracture of JQuery elements and how to move through the DOM tree.

My aim is to highlight (background color) the clicked link (a).
if the "li a" is inside ul which is not the main "menu" ul (meanning sub-menu link) then i want to highlight both the sub menu link and the top menu link.

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="site">
<div id="koteret">
<div id="top_menu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="welcome.html" id="wel" title="HomePge" >home</a></li>
    <li><a href="welcome.html"  id="d" title="c">read</a>
        <ul class="par">
            <li><a href="welcome.html" id="b" title="title" >test</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register_client.aspx" id="c" title="add">addRead</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="books.aspx" title="Books" >Books</a>
           <ul  class="par">
                <li><a href="books.aspx" title="Manage">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="Register_book.aspx" title="addbook">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html" id="a" title="Contact" >CoNTACT</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="test">
<iframe id="con" src="welcome.html">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffsdfdsfsdfwefwfwfw
fwfwefwe<br />fwefwefw</iframe>
<div id="side_bar">fsfdsfsdf</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>

</body>
```

As for the JQuery i tried this:

```
$(this).closest("ul").find("a").attr("id"));
```

and a few other versions with parents but i get "undefined" or empty strings when i check with alerts.
Can you help me understand where is my mistake?
I'm sure it's something very simple i just can't find it.
Thanks

Comment: r u sure `.find("a")` returns any thing ? `.attr("id")` is absolutely right

Comment: There's an extra `)` in your code.

Comment: what does `$(this).closest("ul").find("a")` return ?

Comment: If that's the only JavaScript you have, `this` will point to `window`; also, it should be `.prop('id')`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK  this was a leftover from the alert ().

Comment: @AmirSherafatian - this returns [object object]

Comment: I don't understand your main question, but what you want is that right : http://jsfiddle.net/n4prdphv/?

Comment: so its clear, what you get, is not an element have a `id` attribute

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/tfL0grer/

Comment: Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/tfL0grer/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon this is working for me on JSFiddle but for some reason not on visual studio

Comment: And i don't know what to tell you... I've never worked with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight the submenu link and its top most parent link use the following code:

```
$(this).css("background-color","red");
$(this).parents("li").last().find("a:first").css("background-color","red");
```

The first line highlights the link.

The second line will look for the top-most `'li'` then select its immediate `'a'` tag and highlight it

**UPDATE:**

To remove the highlight of the previous click use a CSS class:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then use the following code:

```
$("#menu").find(".highlight").removeClass('highlight');
$(this).addClass('highlight');
$(this).parents("li").last().find("a:first").addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: this is good but i need to remove the highlight each time i'm clicking on a different menu.
if i'm clicking on another link in the highlighted menu then the new sub-menu link should be highlighted and the second one should go back to the default color.
this helped me anyway, thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to clear the previous highlight each time you click the link